# .NET javascript runtime with XML parsing/editing

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, xml

I have found some javascript runtime for .NET like IronJS, Javascript .NET or Jurassic. However seems none of them support XML parsing/editing.

There's any javascript engine for .NET that supports XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just choose to use the 'XML for < script>' [javascript library](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/website/documentation-w3cdom.html#xpath) which is a pure javascript XML library.

With it I can use any .NET javascript runtime for the XML parsing/editing, including the library in the runtime.